# Typescript compiler selecting wrong overload

Tags: node.js, mongoose, typescript, overloading

In the `mongoose.d.ts` "DefinitelyTyped" file, there are two overloads for the `geoNear` function:

```
geoNear(point: { type: string; coordinates: number[] }, options: Object, callback?: (err: any, res: T[]) => void): Query<T[]>;
geoNear(point: number[], options: Object, callback?: (err: any, res: T[]) => void): Query<T[]>;
```

I have defined `point` as

```
const point = { type: "Point", coordinates: [lng, lat] }
```

where `lng` and `lat` are both `number`s, but but when I call it with this:

```
Location.geoNear(point, {
        spherical: true,
        maxDistance: theEarth.getRadiansFromDistance(maxDistance),
        num: 10
    }, (err, results, stats) => {
        var locations = []
        results.forEach((doc: any) => {
            locations.push({
                distance: theEarth.getDistanceFromRadians(doc.dis),
                name: doc.obj.name,
                address: doc.obj.address,
                rating: doc.obj.rating,
                facilities: doc.obj.facilities,
                _id: doc.obj._id
            })
        })
        res.status(200).json(locations)
    })
```

the compiler complains that

```
Argument of type '{ type: string; coordinates: number[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'
```

How can I force `tsc` to use the first overload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calback you are sending expects 3 parameters, instead of the 2 defined in the interface.
You are sending:

```
 }, (err, results, stats) => {
```

When the method expects:

```
callback?: (err: any, res: T[]) => void
```

Your callback should be:

```
}, (err, results) => {
```

Comment: It appears that the `.d.ts` file at DefinitelyTyped is incorrect for this function. The callback parameter should be `<T>(err: any, result: T[], stats: any) => void`, but your answer was correct.